# selective stoppropagation jquery

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

Javascript code:

```
$(".div1").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".div1 div").slideToggle();
});

$(".div2").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation ();
    $(".div2 div").slideToggle();
});

$(document).click(function(event){
    $(".div1 div,.div2 div").slideUp();
});
```

Suppose I click `.div1` & `.div1 div` slides down. Then i click `.div2` But as `event.stopPropagation` is executed, `.div1 div` doesnot slide up. So what should i do? I dont want to put this code `$(".div1 div").slideUp();` as it makes no sense when there'll be too many divs like this

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, toggle divs? up/down?

Comment: ok Im giving an example. I want to make it work like Facebook Friend requests,Message,Notifications. Click on "notifications" the notification div slide down & then you click on "message" the notification div slide up & the message div slide down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `Event.stopPropagation()`. All the layers of any application should always, at any point, be able to register an event happened.

Instead use the `event.target` and traverse with `.closest()` to achieve the same.

The following will handle infinite numbers of DIVs, so you don't need to rewrite your code. (PS: just add a `.box` to your parent elements to make all simpler)

```js
$(".box").on("click", function(event){
  const $div = $(this).find('div');
  $('.box > div').not($div).slideUp();
  $div.slideToggle();
});

$(document).on("click", function(event){
  if (!$(event.target).closest(".box").length) {
    $(".box > div:visible").slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.box{
  background:#eee;
  width:160px;
  padding:10px 0;
  margin:10px;
}
.box h2{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.box div{
  display:none;
  background:#aaa;
  color:#cf5;
}
```

```html
Click on 'body' to close opened DIVs
  
<div class="div1 box">
  <h2>DIV 1</h2>
  <div>Lorem <br>Ipsum<br>....</div>
</div>
  
<div class="div2 box">
  <h2>DIV 2</h2>
  <div>Lorem <br>Ipsum<br>....</div>
</div>
  
<div class="div3 box">
  <h2>DIV 3</h2>
  <div>Lorem <br>Ipsum<br>....</div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What the demo shows is not my requirement. When I click Div1 it toggles, and then when I click Div2 Div1 doesnt toggle up. I want to make it work like Facebook Friend requests,Message,Notifications. Click on "notifications" the notification div slide down & then you click on "message" the notification div slide up & the message div slide down

Comment: @iThink Sorry for misinterpreting your question. **I've reedited my answer** Take a look and let me know