# Using javascript, how do you skip, or remove, e.stopPropagation() from certain class names in an element?

Tags: javascript, html, stoppropagation

Using javascript, how do you skip, or remove, e.stopPropagation() from certain class names in an element. In this case, the `.trigger` class in the `.dropdown`?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="trigger edit">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="trigger delete">Delete</a>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: *"of all the <a> tags"*? I'm not sure to fully understand your question, but as a side-note, Event.stopPropagation() should **never be used**. There's not a single valid argument in having to stop an Event from bubbling the DOM and therefore notifying other *layers* in your application that something happened. And it can just cause problems. Hope that's the reason you want to (from my understanding) get rid of it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry, I updated the question using class name instead

Comment: Yes, it's more clearer now, thank you. PS: Anyways. Don't use `stopPropagation()` in your applications (Well... unless you really, really know what you're doing)

Comment: thank you, I will read up on event.stopPropagation() in regards to your comments

Comment: You're welcome. I expanded my answer to give a valid reasoning to support my statement. And here's also a similar [scenario example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569193/383904)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go for [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) that will give you the exact clicked element (not necessarily the one that has the Event attached! (`.dropdown`) in your specific case)
- Having that *target* element, traverse the DOM starting (and including) that element up the ancestors chain in search for [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- Use an `if` statement to see if that element is found:

```js
document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const elClassTrigger = e.target.closest(".trigger");
  if ( elClassTrigger ) e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="trigger edit">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="trigger delete">Delete</a>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Important:

as a side-note, `Event.stopPropagation()` **should never be used**. There's not a single valid argument in having to stop an Event from bubbling the DOM and therefore notifying other layers in your application that something happened. And it can just cause problems.

Just a small example:

Imagine a custom dropdown, and a custom modal window, both close if one clicks *somewhere outside - in the Document*. Say the modal is open, and you click *outside* (in the wish to close it) but your click lands on a dropdown element. Congratulations, the dropdown opened, but the modal did not close since the Event did not propagated to notify its listener. Even funnier would be seeing the dropdown suddenly hover over the modal given a higher z-index in CSS! You got the idea.